# Simple code to write a csv file to a MySQL db with Python and SqlAlchemy eats up too much ram. Any best practice to resolve?

Tags: python, mysql, csv, sqlalchemy

I have some code that is writing data to a database, looking at a few hundred thousand rows nothing too extreme, but it causes my dev computer to hang.  The code looks more or less like this.

```
input_reader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
count = 0
for line in input_reader:
    obj = ObjectToEnter(line[1], line[2])
    child_obj = ChildObject(line[5]) #possibly a few children are entered
    obj.relation.append(child_obj)
    session.add(obj)
    count += 1
session.commit()
```

This just eats away at memory, and my instinct says to maybe commit every 500 objects with something like if count%500 == 0:  session.commit()

The question is, is committing every x rows, or maybe flushing once in awhile likely to help with the problem?  Is there some better practice that I'm missing here?  Note this exact code works fine on a smaller dataset that can fit into memory.

Comment: Your instincts are correct. you try to fit the entire session info (which grows as you read more lines) in-memory. the occasional `commit()` should do the trick.

Comment: Sure enough, that did the trick.  I'm left wondering if there is some optimization of the number of commits that you use.  Is every line overkill for example.

Comment: I am not sure what is the size of your data, but a commit per line is pretty much an overkill. I'd go for every 1000 lines or so (but that's a wild guess).